Laravel test is failing abruptly in the CI
I have written EditTaskControllerTest class and implemented the tests. These are working locally but not on CI it is failing only for one case test_should_accept_valid_payload.
Although I did run multiple runs, and got failed for this particular line
$response->assertRedirectToRoute('task.show', [
    'group' => $this->group,
    'task' => $this->task,
]);

In the controller definition, it clearly redirects the user to the task.show
return to_route('task.show', [
      'group' => $group,
      'task' => $task,
]);

I am not keeping you in suspense, the repository can be found here and the failing test case is here.
As you can see on of the test on ubuntu is working fine and another is failing on the same machine.
Now when I clear the database and run the tests again on my system, it is working for me.
EditTaskController.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Tasks;

use App\Enums\TaskStatus;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\Tasks\EditTaskRequest;
use App\Models\Group;
use App\Models\Task;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class EditTaskController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     */
    public function __invoke(EditTaskRequest $request, Group $group, Task $task)
    {
        if ($request->isMethod('GET')) {
            return view('tasks.edit', [
                'task' => $task
            ]);
        }

        $status = $request->safe()->enum('status', TaskStatus::class);
        if ($task->status == TaskStatus::Completed && $status != TaskStatus::Completed) {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'status' => 'Changing task status is not allowed once it is marked as completed.',
            ]);
        }

        $payload = collect($request->safe([
            'title',
            'description',
        ]))->merge([
            'status' => $status
        ]);

        if ($task->status != TaskStatus::Completed && $status == TaskStatus::Completed) {
            $payload = $payload->merge([
                'completed_at' => Carbon::now()
            ]);
        }

        $task->update($payload->toArray());

        return to_route('task.show', [
            'group' => $group,
            'task' => $task,
        ]);
    }
}

EditTaskControllerTest.php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Http\Controllers\Tasks;

use App\Models\Group;
use App\Models\Task;
use App\Models\User;
use Tests\TestCase;

class EditTaskControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    protected Group $group;
    protected Task $task;
    protected User $user;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        User::factory(2)->createMany();
        Group::factory(20)->createMany();
        Task::factory(50)->createMany();

        $this->user = User::query()->whereHas('groups.tasks')->get()->first();
        $this->group = $this->user->groups->toQuery()->whereHas('tasks')->get()->first();
        $this->task = $this->group->tasks->first();
    }


    public function test_should_redirect_to_login_page()
    {
        $response = $this->get(route('task.edit', [
            'group' => $this->group,
            'task' => $this->task
        ]));
        $response->assertRedirectToRoute('auth.login');
    }

    public function test_should_return_403_on_some_other_user()
    {
        $response = $this->actingAs(User::where('id', '!=', $this->group->user_id)->first())->get(route('task.edit', [
            'group' => $this->group,
            'task' => $this->task
        ]));
        $response->assertForbidden();
    }

    public function test_should_return_as_missing_when_not_belongs_to_group()
    {
        /** @var Group $newGroup */
        $newGroup = $this->user->groups->toQuery()->where('id', '!=', $this->group->id)->get()->first();

        $response = $this->actingAs($this->user)->get(route('task.show', [
            'group' => $newGroup,
            'task' => $this->task
        ]));
        $response->assertRedirectToRoute('group.show', [
            'group' => $newGroup,
            'error' => 'Requested task does not exist.'
        ]);
    }

    public function test_should_return_as_missing_when_task_does_not_exist()
    {
        $this->task->delete();

        $response = $this->actingAs($this->user)->get(route('task.edit', [
            'group' => $this->group,
            'task' => $this->task,
        ]));
        $response->assertRedirectToRoute('group.show', [
            'group' => $this->group,
            'error' => 'Requested task does not exist.'
        ]);

        $this->user = User::query()->whereHas('groups.tasks')->get()->first();
        $this->group = $this->user->groups->toQuery()->whereHas('tasks')->get()->first();
        $this->task = $this->group->tasks->first();
    }

    public function test_should_reject_on_invalid_payload()
    {
        $response = $this->actingAs($this->user)->put(route('task.edit', [
            'group' => $this->group,
            'task' => $this->task,
        ]));
        $response->assertSessionHasErrors([
            'title' => 'The title field is required.',
            'status' => 'The status field is required.',
        ]);

        $response = $this->actingAs($this->user)->put(route('task.edit', [
            'group' => $this->group,
            'task' => $this->task,
        ]), [
            'title' => fake()->text(64),
            'description' => fake()->text(),
            'status' => 'erroneous',
        ]);
        $response->assertSessionHasErrors([
            'status' => 'The selected status is invalid.',
        ]);

        $this->actingAs($this->user)->put(route('task.edit', [
            'group' => $this->group,
            'task' => $this->task,
        ]), [
            'title' => fake()->text(64),
            'description' => fake()->text(),
            'status' => 'completed',
        ]);
        $response = $this->actingAs($this->user)->put(route('task.edit', [
            'group' => $this->group,
            'task' => $this->task,
        ]), [
            'title' => fake()->text(64),
            'description' => fake()->text(),
            'status' => 'pending',
        ]);
        $response->assertSessionHasErrors([
            'status' => 'Changing task status is not allowed once it is marked as completed.',
        ]);
    }

    public function test_should_accept_valid_payload()
    {
        $payload = [
            'status' => fake()->randomElement([
                'pending',
                'in-progress',
                'completed',
            ]),
            'title' => fake()->text(64),
            'description' => fake()->text(),
        ];

        $response = $this->actingAs($this->user)->put(route('task.edit', [
            'group' => $this->group,
            'task' => $this->task,
        ]), $payload);

        $response->assertRedirectToRoute('task.show', [
            'group' => $this->group,
            'task' => $this->task,
        ]);
    }
}

routes/auth.php
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LogoutController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\SignupController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
    Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], '/auth/login', LoginController::class)->name('auth.login');
    Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], '/auth/signup', SignupController::class)->name('auth.signup');
});

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/auth/logout', LogoutController::class)->name('auth.logout');
});

routes/web.php
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Groups\CreateGroupController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Groups\DeleteGroupController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Groups\EditGroupController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Groups\ListGroupController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Groups\ShowGroupController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProfileSettings\DeleteProfileSettingsController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProfileSettings\UpdateProfileSettingsController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Tasks\CreateTaskController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Tasks\DeleteTaskController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Tasks\EditTaskController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Tasks\ShowTaskController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('welcome');


require 'auth.php';

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::name('profile.')->prefix('profile')->group(function () {
        Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], 'edit', UpdateProfileSettingsController::class)->name('edit');
        Route::post('delete', DeleteProfileSettingsController::class)->name('delete');
    });

    Route::name('group.')->prefix('groups')->group(function () {
        Route::get('', ListGroupController::class)->name('index');
        Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], 'create', CreateGroupController::class)->name('create');
        Route::missing(function () {
            return to_route('group.index', [
                'error' => 'Requested resource does not exist.',
            ]);
        })->group(function () {
            Route::get('{group}', ShowGroupController::class)->name('show');
            Route::match(['GET', 'PUT'], '{group}/edit', EditGroupController::class)->name('edit');
            Route::match(['GET', 'DELETE'], '{group}/delete', DeleteGroupController::class)->name('delete');
        });
    });

    Route::name('task.')
        ->scopeBindings() // checks if the child model is really a child of the parent
        ->prefix('groups/{group}/tasks')
        ->group(function () {
            Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], 'create', CreateTaskController::class)->name('create');
            Route::missing(function () {
                return to_route('group.show', [
                    'error' => 'Requested task does not exist.',
                    'group' => request()->route()->parameters['group']
                ]);
            })->group(function () {
                Route::get('{task}', ShowTaskController::class)->name('show');
                Route::match(['GET', 'PUT'], '{task}/edit', EditTaskController::class)->name('edit');
                Route::match(['GET', 'DELETE'], '{task}/delete', DeleteTaskController::class)->name('delete');
            });
        });
});

Update 1 
I was using pgsql in the localhost, and sqlite on the CI. When I switched to the sqlite on localhost, it works randomly. Please help me with the fix.
Update 2 
here It worked on 3/4 environments.

Can you share the code in here please? Do not share the repository as it can go down and the question is useless for someone else. Copy-paste (not image, literal text) the test that it is failing please. I am thinking that it may be related to the setup of your test, because it fails as it redirects to the main page instead of the task.show. Are you sure the user is connected and all of that?

Done. Thanks for your time. Yes user should be connected because I am getting the user where task exists User::query()->whereHas('groups.tasks')->get()->first()

Can you share the routes? Also share EditTaskRequest just to be sure about the validation. And do not do ->get()->first() anywhere, as ->get() will always get EVERYTHING, and then you are just selecting the first element with ->first(), you wan to directly do ->first() instead of ->get()->first(), so you do not load EVERYTHING into memory, and the database does also select one element instead of all of them

I think it is related to auth, but you should get redirected to login maybe. Could you update your test adding $response->dump(); before $response->assertRedirectToRoute('task.show'? It will output a lot of info that I think will help when it fails

Adapting to the parallel tests and implementing the RefreshDatabase trait helped me solve this issue.
Here is the commit: https://github.com/tbhaxor/Taskify/pull/3/commits/e91e1e19b55148e01106973c312b7b281d7f1394
